# How to add site models to Cookiecutter Django project

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations, cookiecutter-django

I have a Cookiecutter Django project in which I'd like to add a "SiteSettings" model to control constants. My first instinct was to run `manage.py startapp site`. However I received the following message:

*CommandError: 'site' conflicts with the name of an existing Python module and cannot be used as an app name. Please try another name.*

Upon closer inspection, it appears that Cookiecutter already created a `sites` module within `contrib`, but with no models.py file. So I decided to make a `models.py` with the `SiteSettings` model in this directory.

[image]

However when I run `makemigrations` it says: *No changes detected in app 'sites'*

How can I add my desired model to this module and get migrations working for this module?

Answer (score 1):

You will run into countless problems if you follow this path. Just use another name and do `manage.py startapp newname`.

Comment: Will do. Figured this was more trouble than it's worth